# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException how to handle-7

Tags: java

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
how to remove this exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
   FileUpdate obj = new FileUpdate();
    obj.run();
}

public void run() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String csvFile = "/home/IMRAN/file.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {


        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateobj = new Date();

        String dt = df.format(dateobj);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Rforms", "root", "root12");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {



            String[] emp = line.split(cvsSplitBy);


      //   if (emp[0] != null && emp[1] != null ) {
          //  for(int x = 0; x < emp.length; x++) {
                String t = (String) emp[0].trim();
                String t2 = (String) emp[1].trim();
       }
}
```

Comment: I think you asked the same question yesterday and again today. I asked the same question and will ask again paste the csvFile content.

Comment: You are accessing an array object with wrong index number.means outside the 0 to arr.length -1

Comment: Check length of array before accessing it `emp[0]`, `emp[1]` etc

Comment: "how to remove this exception": Don't access an array with an index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not clear... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occours when you try to access to an object (array element) that does not exist. For example, your array is 7 elements long and you try to access element[8]
Are you sure emp[0] is not null?

Comment: With `emp[0] == null` the code would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

This code below tells that `emp` should always have 2 or more elements.
else you got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
...
String t = (String) emp[0].trim();
String t2 = (String) emp[1].trim();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check length of the emp array before accessing its elements.

```
 if(emp!=null && emp.length==2){      
        String t = (String) emp[0].trim();
        String t2 = (String) emp[1].trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Let's assume  that you have place CSV file and content correctly in that case you can place conditions check per below

```
String[] emp = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
  if (emp.length > N) {

        String t = (String) emp[0] !=null ?emp[0].trim():"";
        String t2 = (String)emp[1] !=null ?emp[1].trim():"";
  }
```

Note that you are aware of number values fetch from the line .

or you can utilize List. this will completely take you out from this issue.

```
List lst= Arrays.asList(emp);
```

Refer java docs for how to utilize List and fetch list from it.